# Will Allah Forgive This Person?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, punishment, forgiveness, tawba

Aoa I wanted to know that if a person commits any major sin knowingly he is disobeying Allah or knowingly transgressing against Allah but then later he feels bad or feels remorseful about the sins he commited  and he does Tawbah And leave that sin and promises to never repeat that sin and does good deeds after...does Allah forgive this type of person? Jazak Allah

Comment: Please Google your questions before asking. This question has already been answered and you can find it with a quick Google search; yes Allah will forgive you.

Comment: Thanks man......

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered countless times on different websites, but I will still answer it.

Yes, Allah will absolutely forgive you and you should have no doubt in that, for he is the oft forgiving and most merciful.

Comment: Thank you my friend